# what is the signal sent by OS when date and time change happens in linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I have written an application program and what to get notified in this application if system date or time changed, the same way if user presses ctrl+c then OS sends sigkill signal. My requirement is to know if date or time change take place at any instance of time.
Dear friend, Can you please suggest me any technique to get notified in application for such events.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `Ctrl-C` in a terminal usually makes the terminal program send the `SIGBREAK` signal. `SIGKILL` is uncatchable.

Comment: https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/9/16/405

Comment: @Some programmer dude, The name of the signal sent by Cltr-C is `SIGINT` :)

Comment: @ikegami Ah yes that's true. Thanks for nitpicking my nitpick... :)

Comment: Hi Friend...thanks for the your replies. I could not find specific signal but with different logic I fixed my issue. I no longer need such signal from OS. Still I will try to explore this part. Thanks to all of u again